# Shared Preferences in ListFragments

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-listfragment

I wanted to share a string between an main activity and my list fragment. So I thought i can use Shared.Preferences. As i'm new to android and just started using shared preferences, m facing this issue.

This is my shared preference class

```
public class AppPrefs { 
    private static final String USER_PREFS = "USER_PREFS"; 
    private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor; 
    private String responseXml = "response_xml_prefs";  
    public AppPrefs(Context context){  
        this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();  
        } 
    public String getResponse_xml() {  
        return appSharedPrefs.getString(responseXml, "unknown");
        } 
    public void setResponse_xml(String _responser_xml) { 
        prefsEditor.putString(responseXml, _responser_xml).commit();
        }

    }
```

This in my mainActivity

```
Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
    AppPrefs appPrefs = new AppPrefs(context); 
    appPrefs.setResponse_xml(responseXml);
```

and this in my ListFragment

```
Context context = this.getActivity(); 
    AppPrefs appPrefs = new AppPrefs(context); 
    String responseXml = appPrefs.getResponse_xml();
```

but when i do `Log.e("responseXml", responseXml);`

m getting a default string "unknown" which i have soted in the shared preference class.
please let me know where have i gone wrong :(

**Update 1**

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {
MyTask myNewTask;
String responseXml;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String requestXml=in.getStringExtra("xml");
    myNewTask = new MyTask(requestXml);
    myNewTask.setOnResultListener(asynResult);
    myNewTask.execute();


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    /** Creating All Tab */
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("All")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<AllMsgFragment>(this, "All", AllMsgFragment.class,responseXml));
    //.setIcon(R.drawable.android);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);


    /** Creating Success Tab */
    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Success")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<SuccessMsgFragment>(this, "Success", SuccessMsgFragment.class,responseXml));
    //.setIcon(R.drawable.apple);
```

I donno how to pass the bundle

```
}

OnAsyncResult asynResult = new OnAsyncResult() {

    @Override
    public void onResultSuccess(final int resultCode, final String responseXml) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                storeData(responseXml);
            }


        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onResultFail(final int resultCode, final String errorMessage) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        });

    }



};

void storeData(String responseXml){
    //this.responseXml=responseXml;
    /*Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
    AppPrefs appPrefs = new AppPrefs(context); 
    appPrefs.setResponse_xml(responseXml);*/

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("responseXml", responseXml);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

}
```

}

its showing null pointer exception

**Edit 2**

Using a static variable solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass the string to your fragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and inside the fragment (i.e. onCreate())

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String myString = bundle.getString(key, defaultValue);
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are stored as singleton. Any `Context` is valid as long as it is in the scope of your application. Your suggestion of using `Bundle` to pass data to Fragment is correct. But, I cannot figure out why OP's approach isn't working.

Comment: I have updated the code. I tried using Bundle. and inside my ListFragment,(onCreateView) i have doneBundle bundle = this.getArguments(); String myString = bundle.getString("responseXml", "unknown"); not m getting an exception : nullpointer

Comment: @user1743673: when and how do you add your fragment to the activity?